# How does the bash command myvar=$(<myfile) work?

Tags: bash

```
myvar=$(<myfile)
```

This reads the contents of `myfile` into the variable `myvar`. It doesn't look like process substitution. It doesn't look like redirection since there is no command that directs into. How does this work?

Comment: It's not process substitution nor redirection, it's just a third syntax(that resembles syntax of both the prior two mentioned features)  for doing what you've mentioned, read the content of a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), section "Command Substitution":

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.